# How to call an activity inside a fragment

Tags: android

I have created a fragment inside an Activity, and now I want to open another application/Activity inside this fragment, Result that I want is, both the activities should be seen on the display (it should not open in another window). Please let me know how can I achieve this.?

Answer (score 7):

Nope you cannot achieve this, you cannot start an activity inside a fragment nor you can show a fragment inside a fragment. For showing multiple layouts in a single screen or activity you need to adjust your activity's layout file and arrange different fragments accordingly ...

Comment: Is it possible to add tabs(using Tabhost) to the fragment,which is sharing screen with another application? 
If so pls let me know..
I am trying many ways to add tabs but every time it throws nullpointerexception when i call addtab() or gettabhost()